# Local dependency cannot be resolved

Tags: move-lang, sui

I know there is a similiar question right below this one but the answer does not solve my issue.
I have a published package and would like to refer to it from another one.
The dependency is defined locally (not git), however the `build` command returns 'Failed to build Move modules: "**Unable to resolve packages for package 'Parent'**".' thus I'm doing something wrong with the linking.

the project structure looks like this:

[image: folder structure]

**Parent Move.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Parent"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet-0.10.0" }
Child = { local = "child" }

[addresses]
parent = "0x0"
child = "0x08f5f5f4101e9c4b2d2b3f212b6e909b48acd02c"
```

**Child Move.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Child"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet-0.10.0" }

[addresses]
child =  "0x0"
```

**foo.Move**

```
module child::foo {
    use sui::tx_context::{TxContext};

    fun init(_: &mut TxContext) {}
    public fun test(): u8 {
        10
    }
}
```

**bar.Move**

```
module parent::bar {
    use sui::tx_context::{TxContext};
    use child::foo::{Self};
    
    fun init(_: &mut TxContext) {
        let value_from_child = foo::test();
     }
}
```

I am on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that module `child` is bound to address `0x0` in package `Child`, but bound to your published address in package `Parent`.  Currently, there are a couple of ways you could get things building.

##### 1. Assign `child` the same address (its published address) in both packages:

(Recommended if `Child` is intended to be published in one place and then reused by everyone there)

**./Move.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Parent"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet-0.10.0" }
Child = { local = "child" }

[addresses]
parent = "0x0"
child = "0x08f5f5f4101e9c4b2d2b3f212b6e909b48acd02c"
```

**./child/Move.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Child"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet-0.10.0" }

[addresses]
child = "0x08f5f5f4101e9c4b2d2b3f212b6e909b48acd02c"
```

##### 2. Assign `child` a placeholder address in `Child` and substitute it in `Parent`.

(Recommended if `Child` is a library that you expect to re-publish along with the packages that use it)

**./Move.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Parent"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet-0.10.0" }
Child = { local = "child", addr_subst = { "child" = "0x08f5f5f4101e9c4b2d2b3f212b6e909b48acd02c" } }

[addresses]
parent = "0x0"
```

**./child/Move.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Child"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet-0.10.0" }

[addresses]
child = "_"
```

Comment: thank you, that worked just fine! appreciate the two given ways and the corresponding use-cases

Comment: ```Child = { local = "child", addr_subst { "child" = "0x08f5f5f4101e9c4b2d2b3f212b6e909b48acd02c" } }
```  
seems to be missing a '=' after `addr_subst`:
('Unable to parse Move package manifest').
  
```Child = { local = "child", addr_subst = { "child" = "0x08f5f5f4101e9c4b2d2b3f212b6e909b48acd02c" } ```

Comment: You're absolutely right (on the missing `=`).  I've edited the answer to include it, thanks!